# Is there a tool that will maintain several Visual studio 2010 pane layouts, and allow user to choose between them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, layout, usability

For example, I'd like to be able to select between layouts when my laptop is docked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked around for a layout switcher as well; no luck AFAIK.

What you can do is to tweak your layout and then export your VS Settings. Do this for each layout you want and then just import the settings as needed. For ease of maintenance, toss the settings in your personal source control for good measure.

For reference, here are some articles that may help with tweaking layouts:

- [Arranging and Using Windows in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx)
- [How to: Arrange and Dock Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx)